# Spring Security and Port Forwarding

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, portforwarding

I have a Spring Boot application running with Spring Security in a Ubuntu server. The application is listening on port 9090 and I have added a port forward from port 80 to port 9090.

However I'm having trouble serving static content via port 80 (getting 403 responses).

If I make the same request via port 9090 the request works ok.

Do I have to add something to the Spring Security config class?

EDIT: The behaviour seems to be somewhat erratic. Just restarted the webserver and it looks that is able to serve some static contents. Html, css and js are working fine. Favicon and some image files are still not working (403 response).

Comment: Can you post your security config class

Comment: Are there any news on this so far?